# How to select the IMG tag based on the attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

```
<IMG height="160" alt="Web Content Image" src="../image/journal/article?img_id=16505&t=1273484793531" width="240" pngSet />
```

I have the this code for the image , and I want to select the image based on the attribute "pngSet"

I am trying this , but not working.

```
$("img[pngSet='']").css('border' ,'1px solid red');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 $("img[pngSet]").css('border' ,'1px solid red');
```

The [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) is just `[attributeName]` :)

Comment: @wombleton - It's not guaranteed to cross-browser though, I can't recall which ones it fails on, but there are a few, or at least used to be.

Answer (score 3):

Should be:

```
$('img[pngSet]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot (using the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)):

```
$("img[pngSet]")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img[pngSet]");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a bad idea to make up attributes. Browsers don't have to support it. Best would be to use a class instead:

```
<IMG height="160" alt="Web Content Image" src="../image/journal/article?img_id=16505&t=1273484793531" width="240" class="pngSet" /> 
$("img.pngSet").css('border' ,'1px solid red');
```